# Defining an abstract multiplication over finite indices

Tags: function-construction, algebra, sets

I would like to define a map (a "multiplication" denoted $\otimes$) over the finite set of symbols $G=\{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h\}$. I would like to define several rules like 
$$a \otimes b= \{b \} $$
$$a \otimes h= \{h,g\} $$

etc. So the mapping is from $G \times G$ to the power set of G (i.e, to the set of all subsets of G). Can someone kindly suggest some ways as to define such an abstract system of labels, and the above map?

Comment: `a\[TensorProduct]h = {h, g}`?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Yes. Tensor product is just a symbol that I am using for the map $\otimes: G \times G \rightarrow P(G) $ where P(G) denotes the power set of G.